# Canonical Header and Canonical resource in Azure Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

Could you guys please help me up on the generic methods available for the canonical header and canonical resource to be constructed for passing in communication to pull data from rest api.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source code for Azure Storage Samples from http://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/61325 (download Storage_REST_CS project) and look for RestHelper.cs class for implementation of these functionalities.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav , I found that after posting here.

Comment: One more thing like is their any generic code available for converting XDocument into listobject/obect returned from ListHostedServices methos.. I tried writing naively but could not come up with...

Comment: If you don't want to write code, you may want to look into this library for implementing service management API: http://fluentmanagement.elastacloud.com/. There was another one available but unfortunately I couldn't find it. Also look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083888/extracting-values-from-xml-returned-by-azure-service-management-api